# Why I can't remove this Foreign Key constraint on a MySql table?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem. I am using **MySql**

I have a **results** table described by this **DDL** statment:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  id        BigInt(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sample_id BigInt(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  genus     VarChar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  doi       NVarChar(128) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  result    NVarChar(2) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  error     Text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE results COMMENT = '';
ALTER TABLE results ADD CONSTRAINT fk_results_pgrfas FOREIGN KEY (sample_id)
  REFERENCES pgrfas (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
CREATE INDEX fk_results_pgrfas 
 ON results(sample_id);
```

As you can see on this table is defined a **FOREIGN KEY** constratint binds together the **results** table with another table named **pgrfas**.

I have to remove this foreing key constraint, I tried with this statment:

```
alter table results drop foreign key fk_results_pgrfas
```

but it doesn't works, MySql give me back this error message:

```
#42000Can't DROP 'fk_results_pgrfas'; check that column/key exists
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly remove this FK?

**EDIT 1:** The statment:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE results;
```

return:

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sample_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `genus` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `doi` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `error` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_results_pgrfas` (`sample_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

So what it means? Have deleted? But what means this section:

```
KEY `fk_results_pgrfas` (`sample_id`)
```

Comment: Does table pgrfas with column (id)  exist in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Check results and pgrfas tables:

```
SELECT * FROM results;
SELECT * FROM pgrfas;
```

Delete values from tables if you can.

Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and verify correct foreign key name.
Drop foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE results DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_results_pgrfas;
```

You created an INDEX with the same name of your foreign key.

I believe it has no relation, but if you have problem try deleting your index and then deleting the foreign key. 
Drop your associated INDEX:

```
DROP INDEX fk_results_pgrfas ON results;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per  show create table output , you don't have a foreign key constaint with name `fk_results_pgrfas`. Instead you have an index `fk_results_pgrfas` .
If you really want to drop/delete this index then run below query.

```
ALTER TABLE `results` DROP INDEX `fk_results_pgrfas`;
```

On the other hand are you sure that below 2 commands were executed successfully ? Because these 2 commands are creating duplicate key for `result` table .

```
ALTER TABLE results ADD CONSTRAINT fk_results_pgrfas FOREIGN KEY (sample_id)
  REFERENCES pgrfas (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
CREATE INDEX fk_results_pgrfas 
 ON results(sample_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what constraint is really exists

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE
        TABLE_NAME        = 'results' AND
        CONSTRAINT_NAME   = 'fk_results_pgrfas' AND
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE   = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

And maybe better to drop constraint if exists:

```
SET @var = IF ((SELECT true FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA      = 'your_database_name' AND
        TABLE_NAME        = 'results' AND
        CONSTRAINT_NAME   = 'fk_results_pgrfas' AND
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE   = 'FOREIGN KEY'), 'alter table results drop foreign key fk_results_pgrfas', 'select 1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @var;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run an SHOW CREATE TABLE results; to make sure the name of foreign key constraint and run the command with the name you get?

ALTER TABLE results DROP FOREIGN KEY <>

Comment: try this command - ALTER TABLE results DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_results_pgrfas